# The head on main shows not declared in this scope error. I need to print the item with data, then find the total from data

Tags: c++

> 1. Write linked list classes(one class for Node and another class for List), which store the items in the transaction.
> 2. Test the classes by printing the items in the linked list
> 3. Show the total price of the transaction.
> 4. Delete an item from the linked list and show new output (total price of the transaction).
>
> The output should look like this: BC Items Price
>
> 10 Pagoda Gnut 110g       3.49     11 Hup Seng Cream Cracker 4.19
> 12 Yit Poh 2n1 Kopi-o     7.28     13 Zoelife SN & Seed      5.24
> 14 Gatsby S/FO Wet&Hard   16.99     15 GB W/G U/Hold 150g     6.49
> Total (GST Incl.) 43.68

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Node class
class Node {


public:
    double data;
    string item;
    Node* next;
    Node() {};
    void setData(double aData) {data = aData; };
    void setString(string aItem) {item = aItem;};
    void setNext(Node* aNext) {next = aNext; };
    double Data() {return data; };
    string String() {return item;};
    Node* Next() {return next; };
};

// List class
class List {
    Node *head;
    public:
        List() { head = NULL; };
        void addNode(double data, string item);
        void total();
        void print(Node **head);
};

//add a node to the list at tail
void List::addNode(double n, string m) {
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode->setData(n);
    newNode->setString(m);
    newNode->setNext(NULL);

    // Create a temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;
    if ( tmp != NULL ) {
    // Nodes already present in the list
    while ( tmp->Next() != NULL ) {
        tmp = tmp->Next();
    }
 // Point the last node to the new node
 tmp->setNext(newNode);
 }
 else {
 // First node in the list
 head = newNode;
 }  
} 

void print(Node **head){
    Node* a = *head;
    cout << "========================================" <<endl;
    cout << "BC Items                        Price" <<endl;
    cout << "========================================" <<endl;

    while(a){
        cout << a ->data << "\t\t";
        cout << a->item << endl;
        a = a->next;
    }
 cout << "========================================" <<endl;
}

void List::total(){
    Node* cur = head;
    double sum=0;
    cout << "Total (GST Incl.)            ";
    while (cur){
        sum = sum + cur->data;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cout << sum;
    cout << "========================================" <<endl;
}

int main() {

List list;

list.addNode(3.49, "10 Pagoda Gnut 110g");  
list.addNode(4.19, "11 Hup Seng Cream Cracker");
list.addNode(7.28, "12 Yit Poh 2n1 Kopi-O");
list.addNode(5.24, "13 Zoelife SN & Seed");
list.addNode(16.99, "14 Gatsby S/FO Wet&Hard");
list.addNode(6.49, "15 GB W/G U/Hold 150g");


list.print(&head);  
list.total();
 return 0;
  }
```

when I try to compile, the error looks like this
[Error] 'head' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Please go over your question and add detail to clarify the problem.  Questions like "is this correct?" are meaningless, and easily _testable_ by you.  Statements like "not sure about this one" do not describe a problem or ask a question.  And the final part "shows the error" -- what error?  You have not described the output you are getting.

Comment: So sorry.  I have already edited some parts. Hope it helps now.

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting, please supply more details.
From glance:

Main doesnt know head

```
list.print(&head);
```

Main doesnt know data

```
list.total(data);
```

Also you dont need these function to accept parameters if your purpose is just to print the total.

void List::total();

For the print functiom:
you should accept `List` as parameter not `node`, because you cant access to `head` - its a List member.

void print(const List& list);

Comment: I have tried the void List::total(); and it works.

Comment: [Error] 'head' was not declared in this scope

Comment: As i wrote... Look at my explenation about your print function

Comment: Sorry about that. I did the same with the list.print and it works now. Thank you.